# Shrink APFS Partition with Catalina

Tags: macos, bootcamp, disk-utility, partition, catalina

I had created a bootcamp partition. I have now removed it *using the Bootcamp Assistant*. I thought I could then recreate it at a larger size. Bootcamp assistant does not allow me to choose a larger size.

I have now tried to see if I can shrink the APFS partition, but disk utility insists the minimum size is 1.74TB. Only 500Gb is actually used.

Why is the minimum size 1.74TB? Is there any way to shrink it?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disk space recovery after failed bootcamp installation attempt on a fusion drive - High Sierra](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/311320/disk-space-recovery-after-failed-bootcamp-installation-attempt-on-a-fusion-drive)

Comment: No, I didn't lose any free space. I removed the Bootcamp volume through Bootcamp assistant and didn't have any issues with that.
My question is about shrinking the APFS partition which that post doesn't seem to address unless I am missing something.

Comment: The answer covers how you can recover more space then shrinking Macintosh HD.

Comment: As mentioned above, I did use Bootcamp assistant to remove the volume.

Comment: Deleting refers to using Disk Utility. Merging is the proper term for BootCamp assistant