# Reclaim lost space from Bootcamp Partition

Tags: bootcamp, high-sierra, diskutil

First off, sorry I didn't understand you had to use apples bootcamp software to deal with bootcamp partitions. I wanted to stop using bootcamp, so I deleted the partition through disk manager some time ago. Since then I have been trying to get the 400GB space back.

Today I followed this thread:
[Cannot delete or merge old boot camp partition in El Capitan](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/235080/cannot-delete-or-merge-old-boot-camp-partition-in-el-capitan)

And I deleted the partition that showed up. But the result is that it has simply vanished, I can't reclaim it, because it does not even show up on disk manager or diskutil.

I have the 3TB fusion drive, but only 2.7 GB is available. I'm on a late '12 imac with high sierra 10.13.3.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

**===== final result ======**

[image]

Comment: Please include the output from `diskutil  cs  list`. Also, what version of macOS are you using? What is the model/year of your Mac?

Comment: Hi David. Added the information requested. Late '12 imac with 10.13.3 high sierra.

Comment: Backup Macintosh HD with Time Machine, completely recreate a proper Fusion Drive and restore the backup! Everything else is a waste of time!

Comment: Klanomath: Already tried that. Wiped everything in the process. Didn't succeed!

Comment: Wiping Macintosh HD is not sufficient. You have to delete the logical volume and logical volume group, completely erase disk0 and 1 (each to one visible HFSJ+ volume) and finally [recreate an LVG and LV (Fusion Drive)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/70113/93229). After restoring the backup, download and reinstall High Sierra 10.13.3 to restore the Recovery HD. Simply installing High Sierra over an existing High Sierra install won't delete your TM restored data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest creating the USB flash drive installer, because it takes you 30+ minutes to boot to Internet Recovery. If you want to use Internet Recovery then use the alternate instructions given below.

1. Backup Macintosh HD with Time Machine to an external drive.
2. Download High Sierra from the Apps Store. If the download software starts to execute, cancel the execution.
3. Transfer High Sierra to a USB flash drive. See [How to create a bootable installer for macOS](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372).
4. Restart the Mac and immediately hold down the <kbd>option</kbd> key. When the Startup Manager icons appear, choose the installer.
5. From the menu bar, choose the Terminal application.
6. Enter the commands given below to create the new Logical Volume Group (LVG)

   ```
   diskutil  unmount  "Macintosh HD"
   diskutil  cs  createLVG  "Macintosh HD"  disk0  disk1
   ```
7. Use the command below to determine the UUID of the new LVG.

   ```
   diskutil  cs  list
   ```

   For example, you would look for a line similar to what is shown below.

   ```
   +-- Logical Volume Group A8CEEF75-6839-4806-B799-97CF0CAABB7C
   ```
8. Enter the command given below to create a new Logical Volume (LV).

   ```
   diskutil  coreStorage  createVolume  <UUID from previous step>  jhfs+ "Macintosh HD"  100%
   ```

   For example, drawing on the example in the previous step, you should enter a command similar to what is given below.

   ```
   diskutil  coreStorage  createVolume  A8CEEF75-6839-4806-B799-97CF0CAABB7C  jhfs+  "Macintosh HD"  100%
   ```

   > Note: Replace `A8CEEF75-6839-4806-B799-97CF0CAABB7C` with the UUID you determined in the previous step.
9. Quit the Terminal and use Time Machine to restore your files.

   > Note: The OP has reported a complete verbatim restore works better than selectively restoring files.
10. Install High Sierra. Be sure to select that you what to keep your files.

### Alternate Instructions

> Note: Requires macOS Sierra 10.12.4 or later,.

There instruction require booting to Internet Recovery.

1. Backup Macintosh HD with Time Machine to an external drive.
2. Boot to Internet Recovery. At startup or restart, immediately hold down the <kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> key combination.
3. From the menu bar, choose the `Utilities->Terminal`.
4. Enter the commands given below to create the new Logical Volume Group (LVG)

   ```
   diskutil  unmount  "Macintosh HD"
   diskutil  cs  createLVG  "Macintosh HD"  disk0  disk1
   ```
5. Use the command below to determine the UUID of the new LVG.

   ```
   diskutil  cs  list
   ```

   For example, you would look for a line similar to what is shown below.

   ```
   +-- Logical Volume Group A8CEEF75-6839-4806-B799-97CF0CAABB7C
   ```
6. Enter the command given below to create a new Logical Volume (LV).

   ```
   diskutil  coreStorage  createVolume  <UUID from previous step>  jhfs+ "Macintosh HD"  100%
   ```

   For example, drawing on the example in the previous step, you should enter a command similar to what is given below.

   ```
   diskutil  coreStorage  createVolume  A8CEEF75-6839-4806-B799-97CF0CAABB7C  jhfs+  "Macintosh HD"  100%
   ```

   > Note: Replace `A8CEEF75-6839-4806-B799-97CF0CAABB7C` with the UUID you determined in the previous step.
7. Quit the Terminal and use Time Machine to restore your files.

   > Note: The OP has reported a complete verbatim restore works better than selectively restoring files.
8. Install High Sierra. Be sure to select that you what to keep your files.

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks! Can't wait to try it out. Time Machine is still chugging along, not even halfway through. But I can make the bootable installer in the meantime. Will report back once I am on the other side..

Comment: Check out the latest image i added to the post.. isn't it a thing of beauty? So clean and simple. Thank you so much for the detailed instructions - everything went well with formatting, the thing that gave me trouble was time machine in the end. Apparently selective restoring is bugged for me, so ended up with a complete verbatim restore, which I am typing this from now. So everything back to normal and I have my 400 GB back. Thanks again!!

Comment: I assumed klanomath intended for you to do a complete restore, then install macOS. I will have to add this to the answer.

Comment: Thanks @DavidAnderson, you saved my day! I had a lost Bootcamp partition and there was no way to get the lost space back. Creating a completely new Logical Volume Group solved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your partitions are fairly messed up. You seem to have lost your Recovery partition and your have 2 Core Storage partitions on physical `disk1`.

You will have to boot to Internet Recovery to enter these next 2 commands. The purpose of executing these commands is to create a partition so subsequent `diskutil` commands will not fail. These commands does not recreate the missing Recover partition. You still will not have a Recovery partition.

```
gpt -f add -b 3518304760 -s 262144 -i 3 -t 426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC /dev/disk1
```

The next command will format the newly created partition.

```
newfs_hfs -J -v "Boot OS X" disk1s3
```

You can now boot back to macOS and enter the next 2 commands.

```
diskutil cs resizePV 283F0C97-1406-4410-9E1B-7B46DF89373B 0
diskutil cs resizeLV 1F16BBE1-0369-44F2-BDCF-A21CFA0909CC 0
```

I do not know of a way to replace the missing Recovery partition, other than reinstall macOS. At some point during an upgrade, I image the Recovery partition will be recreated in place of the empty `disk1s3`.

For now, you can use Internet Recovery, if necessary. Another option would be to download, but not install, High Sierra from the Apps Store. You then could create an USB flash drive installer. This installer would include all of the functionality of the missing Recovery partition. The instructions for creating the flash drive are given at the Apple website: [How to create a bootable installer for macOS](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372). Again this is optional, since you can use Internet Recovery.

Comment: Yes I am of the same belief. The suggested command failed as you predicted: Error: -69722: You can't perform this resize unless it has a booter (target partition is probably too small. I will try to figure out how to do screenshots in internet recovery mode and reply back.

Comment: You can copy the from the Terminal application window and paste into Safari. Do not worry about the format, I can easily fix that.

Comment: Wow took 35 minutes to boot into internet recovery. I added a terminal screenshot to the post.

Comment: Oh by the way the missing partition is #3 on disk 1. You can see there is a blank space where it used to be.

Comment: Thanks so much for the continued help. Entering the first command, I get an error saying "entry at index 3 is not free" and I can't seem to progress from there. Is it easier to completely wipe everything and start from beginning with a time machine? I can do that as well.. prepared for anything to solve this issue.

Comment: Since you appear to be new to Ask Different, you should know that @klanomath has far more experience that anyone else at solving problems of your kind. If you can use time machine, then his solution would probably work better than mine. I was just trying to recover the lost space. His solution repairs the entire drive.

Comment: When presented with more than one solution, frequently the better solution is offered by someone with more reputation points. I have 7K+, but klanomath has 43K+. You should pick the best solution for you. This is the best way to help others who may have the same problem in the future.

Comment: As for the error message you received. This indicates the missing Recovery partition location may still be stored in the MBR table. You could try booting to internet recovery and executing the command `fdisk /dev/disk1`, then post the output to your question. However, as I already stated, klanomath's approach would repair the entire drive. BTW, you can address a comment directly to klanomath by including an @klanomath somewhere in the comment.

Comment: Okay well having a restored fusion drive appeals to me, one where it's not broken into bits and pieces because of me applying the wrong tools at some point. Running the time machine atm, and when done will try approach by @klanomath. I am just worried I am not versed enough in gpt/diskutil to follow the general instructions, is there a more specific guide for beginners somewhere on how to completely restore the fusion drive?

Answer (score 0):

Mojave and high sierra Lost bootcamp space

do this steps ,
probably you will lose your data.

1) Backup your Mac

2) Download the os which ever you are using right now

3) create a bootable flash drive
-https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372

[link](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372)

4) shutdown your macbook and attach a drive

5) hold *option* button and press power button keep holding option button

6) select installer

7) go to utility tab from tastbar and select terminal

8) fire this commands it will erase your entire partition
diskutil umountDisk /dev/disk0
gpt destroy /dev/disk0

9) now check space using this command 
diskutil list

10 ) now you have your space back

11) reboot mac and install your os from flash drive

ENJOY !!!!