# Reclaim lost (unpartitioned) space on Fusion disk

Tags: bootcamp, imac, partition

First my Bootcamp crashed due to a Win update on my iMac. Then I tried to fix it, assisted by an AppleCare person (using Diskutil and Terminal). Now it seems I have lost 500GB+ on my Fusion drive, and I have not been able to restore Bootcamp using BA.

I know very little about terminal, and don't know for to regain the lost space and make the fusion disk ready for setting up Bootcamp again. Help would be very welcome!!

Thanks!
Tormod

I'm attaching a couple of screenshots that probably shows the situation currently.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The posting the output from the command `diskutil list` would be helpful.

Comment: @DavidAnderson Thanks for the suggestion. I have added it :) (How do I make the name a link?)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the commands below will return the free space to your "Macintosh HD" volume.

```
newfs_hfs  -J  -v  "Recovery HD"  /dev/disk1s3
diskutil  resizevolume  disk1s3  650M
diskutil  unmount  disk1s3
diskutil  cs  resizePV  2110ADEC-ADAD-46C8-AE19-24B589F695E7  0
diskutil  cs  resizeLV  F8F6DA73-C7F8-42FD-AF12-A896F44CD1BB  0
```

Comment: Wow. Thank you very much @David Anderson! I will try that tomorrow morning!

Comment: I get an error message when entering the first resizevolume command (650M): Unable to resize because file system volume format does not does not support resizing.

Comment: The message indicates your Recovery Partition has been damaged. I will update my answer in an attempt to bypass the problem. This may recover the space, but you will not have a functioning Recovery partition. You would be better off following [this accepted answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/316425/lost-my-400gb-bootcamp-partition-how-can-i-reclaim-this-space/316500#316500).

Comment: Is that a procedure for a fusion drive?

Comment: The instructions are basically the same as Apple has published at the website [How to fix a split Fusion Drive](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207584). Your Fusion drive may not be split, but the instructions should still work.